# Is it necessary to perform ghusl after masturbation even if I didn't ejaculate?

Tags: ghusl, masturbation

Is it necessary to take a shower after masturbation even if one did not ejaculate?

Comment: Ghusl is required after masturbation with ejaculation keeping in mind that Masturbation is a big sin ,one should repent.

Comment: This question shows absolutely no focus or research effort; as written, this will just attract opinions rather than actual practical answers.

Comment: @goldPseudo why? i think there's a great consensus that is shown in the answer of servant!

Answer (score 3):

All praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions.

Ali r.a narrated: "**I asked the Prophet peace be upon him about Al-Madhi. He said: "For Al-Madhi is Wudu, and for AI-Mani is Ghusl**."([Tirmidhi on Book of Purification](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/114)).,,and madhi is uretheral fluid and mani is Semen.

If you have not observed Semen,,In this case you dont need to perform Ghusl but wudhu would be obligatory for prayers.

Aishah r.anarrated: "**The Prophet peace be upon him was asked about a man who finds wetness and he does not remember having a wet dream. So he said: 'He is to perform Ghusl. And (he was asked) about a man who had a wet dream but does not find any wetness, so he said: 'No Ghusl is required of him.' Umm Salamah said: 'O Messenger of Allah! Is the woman required to perform Ghusl if she sees that?' He replied: 'Yes. Indeed women are the partners of men**.'"([Tirmizi](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/113))

Answer (score -7):

No it's not necessary because you didn't have sex.  Ghusl would be required if you had actual sex with a female, even if you didn't ejaculate.

Comment: Ghusl would be required after masturbation resulting in ejaculation.

Comment: That's your opinion.  There's no evidence for that.  Ejaculation isn't the reason for Ghusl.

Comment: Ali r.a  narrated:
"I asked the Prophet peace be upon him about Al-Madhi. He said: "For Al-Madhi is Wudu, and for AI-Mani is Ghusl."(Tirmidhi on Book of Purification).,,and madhi is uretheral fluid and mani is Semen.

Comment: Aishah r.anarrated:
"The Prophet peace be upon him was asked about a man who finds wetness and he does not remember having a wet dream. So he said: 'He is to perform Ghusl. And (he was asked) about a man who had a wet dream but does not find any wetness, so he said: 'No Ghusl is required of him.' Umm Salamah said: 'O Messenger of Allah! Is the woman required to perform Ghusl if she sees that?' He replied: 'Yes. Indeed women are the partners of men.'"(Tirmizi)