# Is it necessary to do Ghusal after masturbation?

Tags: ghusl, masturbation

As it is necessary  to  do ghusl after masturbating. Can we do a quick one as in only  wash your body quickly and come out?? Or doing a proper ghusl is necessary??

Comment: See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27701/13438 What upset her when she was ill was that she observed the Prophet’sbehavior to have changed toward her

Answer (score 1):

Firstly masturbation is sinful, you must avoid it and resort to lawful means of fulfilling your physical need i.e marriage.

> And they who guard their private parts Except from their wives or
>   those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed -
>   But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors -

Secondly, if masturbation is done it is necessary to do proper ghusal to remove its uncleanliness. Because Islam teaches to do ghusal to remove state of Janabah.

> in a state of janabah, except those passing through [a place of
>   prayer], until you have washed [your whole body] (4:43)
>
> And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves. (5:6)

Janabah is induced by any action which causes secretion of maniy with pleasure, including wet dream and masturbation

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/170796/what-is-the-janaabah-that-makes-ghusl-obligatory